# insert a multiple rows and a common value using stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have custom type (Table type) in sql server 2008.

```
   CREATE TYPE RequestingDatesType AS TABLE
   (
   LeaveDate datetime,
   IsHoliday bit
   )
```

I have a store procedure

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE CreateLeaveRequest
    @EmployeeId int,
    @LeaveTypeId int,
    @LeaveDescription varchar(50)
    @TableVariable RequestingDatesType READONLY
    AS
      DECLARE @LeaveId INT

      //1st insert command
      INSERT INTO tblLeaveMaster(EmployeeId,LeaveTypeId,LeaveDescription)
      VALUES(@EmployeeId,@LeaveTypeId,@LeaveDescription)
      SET @LeaveId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

      //2nd insert command
      INSERT INTO tblLeaveDetails(LeaveId,LeaveDate,IsHoliday)
      VALUES(@LeaveId, LeaveDate(*from custom type*), IsHoliday(*from custom type*))
```

My question is how can i insert values for 2nd insert command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use something like this:

```
//2nd insert command
  INSERT INTO tblLeaveDetails(LeaveId,LeaveDate,IsHoliday)
  SELECT @LeaveId, LeaveDate, IsHoliday FROM @TableVariable
```